# How to create responsive buttons?

Tags: html, css, button, responsive

I have created multiple buttons in a horizontal line but now I have noticed that they are not responsive yet when I lower the browser size.

I have managed to make my logo responsive with `calc(100%-1em);` but I guess that won't help because the buttons are not `width: 100%` and I have multiple buttons in a row.

The scroll bar on the right is always on the button which I don't want to have.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

```css
.buttons-header {
margin-left: 1.5em;
}  



.buttons    {
            border: none;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 2em;
            width: 20em;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            margin-top: 0.5em;
            padding: 0.4em 0.4em;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-style: normal;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #858585;
            color: #f0ffff;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
```

html:

```
 <div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Flex` which has been added in HTML5.

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.buttons-header {
margin-left: 1.5em;
} 
.buttons{
            border: none;
            height: 2em;
            width: 20em;
            line-height: 3em;
            margin-right:0.5em;
            margin-top: 0.5em;
            padding: 0.4em 0.4em;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-style: normal;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #858585;
            color: #f0ffff;
            cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
<div class="buttons-header"> <a href="https:www.sample.info/" class="buttons">News</a></div>
</div>
```

P.S. you can further play with `line-width` and `margin-right` to the get desired result.

Comment: If my this is the answer to your question, please upvote it and accept as the answer, so the question can be close then and others can find the solution easily later.

Comment: This is not the solution for my problem, because now my buttons are without any space in between in a row and when I shrink the size of my browser window the scroll bar is still above the edge of my button.

Comment: I tried it out but it doesn't work properly because I define the button width to 20em and I want it to shrink when I shrink the window size.

Comment: Then you should not give the exact size, use percentage like % otherwise you can use media queries but first one is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
display:block;
```

in the place of

```
display:inline-block;
```

in the case of phones

Comment: This doesn't work. The scroll bar is right on the buttons right edge.

Answer (score 0):

```html
`<div style="text-align: center; width: auto;">
  <div style="margin:5px; display: inline-block;"><button name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" >Save</button>
    </div>
  <div style="margin:5px; display: inline-block;"><button name="submit" type="submit" value="Cancel" >Cancel</button></div>
</div>`
```

Horizontally button Show in web and mobile view